# How do I get the exact size of the multiprocessing queue??? docs says it's not reliable. Any way to solve this?

Tags: python-3.x, time, queue, multiprocessing

I have this code which has two processes
one is enqueue another is dequeue.

I need to check the the size of the queue for every 60 seconds.
q.size() does give the result but i want result should be accurate.
so are there any other ways to do it??

To be exact i need to monitor the input and output of the queue per minute and the size of the queue per minute.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import os
import time
import datetime as dt
import statsd
import random

statsd_client = statsd.StatsClient(host="localhost", port=8125, 
prefix=None, maxudpsize=512, ipv6=False)


q = Queue()


#put_timer = statsd_client.timer('put')
def queue_add_proc1():
    print("process 1 Id :", os.getpid())
    print("adding items to queue")
    x = 0
    upload_time = time.time()

    enque_count=0

    while x < 10000:
        #put_timer.start()
        curr_time = time.time()
        if curr_time - upload_time > 60:
            statsd_client.incr('enque_count_everyMinute', enque_count)
            statsd_client.incr('queue_size_enqueing', q.qsize())

            print("metric sent")
            enque_count = 0
            upload_time = curr_time
        q.put(x*2)
        #put_timer.stop(send=True)
        print("added to queue")
        x =x+ 1
        enque_count+=1
        time.sleep(0.014)
        print("done")


#pop_timer = statsd_client.timer('get')
def queue_pop_proc2():
    print("Process 2 ID :",os.getpid())
    print("popping values from queue")
    upload_time = time.time()
    deque_count = 0
    while not q.empty():
        curr_time = time.time()
        if curr_time - upload_time > 60:
            # upload dequed count
            statsd_client.incr('deque_count_everyMinute', deque_count)
            statsd_client.incr('queue_size_dequeing', q.qsize())
            print("metric sent")
            deque_count = 0
            upload_time = curr_time

        print(" popped item ", q.get())
        print("dequeued")
        deque_count += 1
        time.sleep(0.03)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    msgs_added_each_minute = list()
    msgs_popped_each_minute = list()

    print("Main process ID :", os.getpid())

    p1 = Process(target=queue_add_proc1)

    p2 = Process(target=queue_pop_proc2)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p2.join()
    p1.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `queue.qsize()` is accurate. The inaccuracy lies in the way users often use it.

As `Queue` is shared concurrently between different threads/processes, when process A checks its size process B might interleave its execution and change it. This might lead to logic issues.

Consider the following example:

```
queue.put("something")

def process_a(queue):
    """Does something if queue has at least one element."""
    if queue.qsize() > 0:
        # now, Process B takes over and steals the only element in the queue
        element = queue.get()  # UNEXPECTED: process A will block here 
        do_something(element)

def process_b(queue):
    """Gets an element from the queue."""
    queue.get()

a = Process(process_a, args=(queue,))
b = Process(process_b, args=(queue,))
a.start()
b.start()
```

The issue here is the logic is relying on the queue specific state and acting upon it. Yet the queue state might change at any point in a concurrent scenario. Hence the logic above would not work as expected.

For your specific use case this should not be an issue as what you are doing is monitoring the queue state in a point in time. Therefore, you don't care if the queue has a different size one millisecond later. What you care about is the average throughput of the queue.

Comment: should queue.qize() be queue.qsize()?